# Highstock tooltip dateTimeLabelFormats for week not working correctly

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use the dateTimeLabelFormats variable to customize the text displayed in a StockChart.
At this URL (it's in a test environment):
http://isplife.stage.h-art.it/it/prodotti/prospettiva-20/fondi/investi-con-me-attivo-forte
if you look at the first chart, Andamento del Fondo Interno, my custom label for the tooltip

```
     day:"%d/%m/%Y"
```

is working correctly.
If you look at this page:
http://isplife.stage.h-art.it/it/prodotti/prospettiva-20/fondi/el-prospettiva-monetario-euro
the same chart, which groups data by weeks since there's lots of data, the label still shows the default "Week from ..." label, even though we've customized it as follows:

```
    week:"Settimana del %d/%m/%Y"
```

The code can be found here:
http://isplife.stage.h-art.it/jscript/fund.js
line 75. Is it a bug? Any ideas?

Comment: Can't see the "Week from ..." in your example link.

Comment: In this page:
http://isplife.stage.h-art.it/it/prodotti/prospettiva-20/fondi/el-prospettiva-monetario-euro
If you hover over the graph, the tooltips say "Week from"
You can see a screenshot here:
http://www.hce.it/immagini-siti/highcharts_screenshot.png

Comment: Indeed looks like a possibly bug, meanttime you can use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and customise content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to precisely work with your code as you've provided no minimal example of your problem, but your problems seems to be that you are setting [`tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.date) when you should be setting [`plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats), or possibly both.

The reasoning for this can be read from the `tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats` API description:

> Note that when data grouping applies, the date time label formats are pulled from **dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats** instead, because it also allows formatting of time spans.

Data grouping is quite common with Highstock, so this will often be the case. To remedy this you can add the following code to the fund.js chart options (above `tooltip` f.x.):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
               millisecond: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L', '-%H:%M:%S.%L'],
               second: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', '-%H:%M:%S'],
               minute: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
               hour: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
               day: ['%A, %b %e, %Y', '%A, %b %e', '-%A, %b %e, %Y'],
               week: ['Settimana del %d/%m/%Y', '%A, %b %e', '-%A, %b %e, %Y'],
               month: ['%B %Y', '%B', '-%B %Y'],
               year: ['%Y', '%Y', '-%Y']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've only edited the part that will test if your week works, but as you can see this has slots for time spans as well. From the documentation:

> For each of these array definitions, the first item is the format used when the active time span is one unit. For instance, if the current data applies to one week, the first item of the week array is used. The second and third items are used when the active time span is more than two units. For instance, if the current data applies to two weeks, the second and third item of the week array are used, and applied to the start and end date of the time span.